# Does JAXP natively parse HTML?

Tags: html, parsing

So, I whip up a quick test case in Java 7 to grab a couple of elements from random URIs, and see if the built-in parsing stuff will do what I need.

Here's the basic setup (with exception handling etc omitted):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dbuild = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dbuild.parse("uri-goes-here");
```

With no error handler installed, the parse method throws exceptions on fatal parse errors.

When getting the standard Apache 2.2 directory index page from a local server: a SAXParseException with the message *White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.* The doctype looks ok to me, whitespace and all.

When getting a page off a Drupal 7 generated site, it never finishes. The parse method seems to hang. No exceptions thrown, never returns.

When getting http://www.oracle.com, a SAXParseException with the message *The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".*

---

So it would appear that the default setup I've used here doesn't handle HTML, only strictly written XML.

My question is: can JAXP be used out-of-the-box from openJDK 7 to parse HTML from the wild (without insane gesticulations), or am I better off looking for an HTML 5 parser?

PS this is for something I may not open-source, so licensing is also an issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560783/i-need-to-parse-non-well-formed-xml-data-html) has a couple of solutions. JAXP apparently only works on well formed XML. You'd need to convert the HTML to XHTML before subjecting it to the JAXP's standard parser.

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much sums up what I'd surmised, that you need well formed XML for JAXP. I'll look through and find something quick-n-dirty, either a converter or html parser. Or even (shudder) cruft a partial parser :)

Comment: As long as you don't use Regular Expressions, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I only want one problem at a time :D